# What could keep the JVM from exiting after a crash in native code?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a C++ library that I call from Java via JNI. There's a bug in the C++ code that occasionally crashes the JVM. To be robust to such crashes, I have wrapped the Java program in a shell script that relaunches java when it exits. Most of the time this works, but once in a while the JVM crashes (prints a native stack trace to stderr, can no longer be attached to by a java debugger, stops consuming any appreciable amount of CPU time) but doesn't exit, so it doesn't get relaunched until I kill it by hand. Why might this happen and what can I do to prevent it?

I'm running under linux. After the crash, the JVM doesn't respond to SIGTERM, only to SIGKILL. When I attach to the JVM process with a native debugger, I see that the threads are all blocked in  __kernel_vsyscall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW I eventually traced these deadlocks to a [bug in glibc's malloc](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=956). It's been known for years and apparently there are no plans to fix it. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment specifically to the process behavior, though I'd be inclined to use something like Tanuki's service wrapper. It actively monitors the JVM and will kill it under these circumstances and restart the service.

Answer (score 1):

Can you write some C++ code which responds to the mentioned bug gracefully and then throw a proper exception back to the Java layer?